# How to add classes in different files into one module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, module

I currently creating a gem, so, I have a folder with different files, which contains different classes, this folder will be updated with more files and also current ones will be updated as well, in another file I have a module that should contain these classes.

Currently, I add manually to the module all the classes:

File1.rb:

```
module MyModule
    class ClassA
        # code here
    end
end
```

File2.rb:

```
module MyModule
    class ClassB
        # code here
    end
end
```

But, since I will add more classes and current classes will be updated this is not optimal and very dangerous to maintain clean, so is there any other way to add classes in different files in one module set in another file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that my question was answered before in another question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582046/add-existing-classes-into-a-module
Thanks for the help 'down voters', I wouldn't find it if it wasn't for you!
(sarcasm)

Answer (score 1):

No there is no another way and I don't see any danger in doing it the way you did (correct way).